# How to send data of the list item of a custom arraylist when clicked to another activity?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-listview, onclicklistener

I have an array list of custom Song objects and I want to send the song name, artist name and the album cover image to another activity (Song Activity) when a particular song item of the listview is clicked. I have created a SongActivity for showing the now playing screen for the song that the user has selected.

**(SONGS LIST ACTIVITY)** This contains the songs list.

```
 public class SongsListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.songs_list);
    ArrayList<Song> songs = new ArrayList<Song>();
            songs.add(new Song("Earthquake","Marshmello and TYNAN",R.mipmap.earthquake));
        .....

            final SongAdapter adapter = new SongAdapter(this, songs);


            ListView listView = findViewById(R.id.list);

            listView.setAdapter(adapter);

            ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
            listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                    Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), SongActivity.class);

                }
            });

        }
    }
```

**(SONG ACTIVITY)** This activity starts when a particular song object is clicked by the user

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class SongActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.song_activity);
        ImageView songImage = findViewById(R.id.songImage);
        TextView songName = findViewById(R.id.songName);
        TextView artistName = findViewById(R.id.artistName);

        Intent intent = getIntent();

        songImage.setImageResource(intent.getIntExtra("image",0));
        songName.setText(intent.getStringExtra("songName"));
        artistName.setText(intent.getStringExtra("artistName"));

    }
}
```

**(SONG ADAPTER)**

```
public class SongAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

    public SongAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<Song> songs) {

        super(context, 0, songs);
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // Check if the existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
        View listItemView = convertView;
        if(listItemView == null) {
            listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
                    R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        }


        Song currentSong = (Song) getItem(position);

        TextView nameTextView = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.song_name);

        nameTextView.setText(currentSong.getSongName());

        TextView artistTextView = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.artist_name);

        artistTextView.setText(currentSong.getArtistName());

        ImageView iconView = (ImageView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.song_icon);

        iconView.setImageResource(currentSong.getImageResourceId());

        return listItemView;
    }

}
```

Comment: U need to Parcelize you custom model and then sent to using intent. intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, mMenuScreenShotList)

Comment: edit your question check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Song Model(Class) Should look like this

```
    import android.os.Parcel;
    import android.os.Parcelable;

    public final class Songs implements Parcelable {
        public static final Parcelable.Creator CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator() {
            @Override
            public Songs createFromParcel(final Parcel source) {
                return new Songs(source);
            }

            @Override
            public Songs[] newArray(final int size) {
                return new Songs[size];
            }
        };
        private String songName;
        private String artistName;
        private Integer imageId;

        public Songs() {
        }

        public Songs(final String songName, final String artistName, final Integer imageId) {
            this.songName = songName;
            this.artistName = artistName;
            this.imageId = imageId;
        }

        protected Songs(final Parcel in) {
            this.songName = in.readString();
            this.artistName = in.readString();
            this.imageId = (Integer) in.readValue(Integer.class.getClassLoader());
        }

        public String getSongName() {
            return songName;
        }

        public void setSongName(final String songName) {
            this.songName = songName;
        }

        public String getArtistName() {
            return artistName;
        }

        public void setArtistName(final String artistName) {
            this.artistName = artistName;
        }

        public Integer getImageId() {
            return imageId;
        }

        public void setImageId(final Integer imageId) {
            this.imageId = imageId;
        }

        @Override
        public int describeContents() {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public void writeToParcel(final Parcel dest, final int flags) {
            dest.writeString(this.songName);
            dest.writeString(this.artistName);
            dest.writeValue(this.imageId);
        }
    }
```

In your `SongListActivity`

```
    listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                    Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), SongActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("SONG_DATA", songList.get(position));
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
```

And at last in `onCreate()` of your `SongActivity` you have to get the intent and get the data like

```
if (getIntent() != null) {
    Song song = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("SONG_DATA");
    // now you have got song object, You can do rest of operations
}
```

Comment: To make any data model Parcelable, Just add Parcelable plugin in your android studio from setting->Plugins. Then inside your data class just press `alt+insert` and select `Parcelable`, The Plugin will create Parcelable code for you.

Comment: The data gets transferred now but when i run the app it crashes.

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.musify/com.example.musify.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setOnItemClickListener(android.widget.AdapterView$OnItemClickListener)' on a null object reference

Comment: your `listView` is null. make sure that `findViewById(R.id.list);` doesn't return null.

Answer (score 2):

Paracelize your modal like this

```
    public class Student implements Parcelable {

    private Integer rollno;
    private String name;
    private Integer age;


    protected Student(Parcel in) {

        age = in.readInt();
        name  = in.readString();
        rollno = in.readInt();

    }

    public Student(Integer age, String name, Integer rollno) {
        this.age = age;
        this.name = name;
        this.rollno = rollno;
    }


    public static final Creator<Student> CREATOR = new Creator<Student>() {
        @Override
        public Student createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new Student(in);
        }

        @Override
        public Student[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Student[size];
        }
    };


    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    public Integer getRollno() {
        return rollno;
    }

    public void setRollno(Integer rollno) {
        this.rollno = rollno;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Integer getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(Integer age) {
        this.age = age;
    }



    public static Creator<Student> getCREATOR() {
        return CREATOR;
    }


  @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int i) {

        parcel.writeInt(age);
        parcel.writeString(name);
        parcel.writeInt(rollno);


    }
}
```

> And then set and get using intent

```
intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, studentList) 
intents.getParcelableArrayList<Student>(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM)
```

Comment: Which class should I parcelize? And how should i call it so i get the song name, artist name and associated image in the SongActivity and get it to display the TextViews and ImageView respectively. It would be really helpful if you can provide the code. Thanks!

Comment: You need to parcelize your song modal class.